# How can I enable wireless interfaces on TWRP terminal with no OS no ADB (Android)

Tags: android

I had some problems flashing a new ROM on my android phone. The result is that I have no OS running/installed on it and I can't access the device from my Mac (drivers should be ok).

I have no ROM stored on the device so I can't install a new/old one. If I can't connect the device using adb/fastboot, how can I push a new OS to install? (Already tried ADB sideload but no detect the device)

I've tried to enable the wireless interface, connect to my WiFi and download the files using wget. But I can't even find it. Using ifconfig only shows those:

- dummy0
- lo
- sit0

The only way I can interact with the device is using the terminal included in TWRP. If I can't access the device using USB I guess it won't detect an OTG connector. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I find myself in the exact same position and also thought of using `wget` to rescue. How did you end up solving this?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't.. Hope anyone could help. I have my old phone bricked.

Comment: Even though I knew changing cable could be an influence it tried 2 and it didn't change. Using a genuine brand cable finally solved as I could mount my phone! It's now reinstalled and I could boot a new LineageOS :)

Comment: Did you solve it with just a brand cable? Where could i find someone?

Comment: Yes, that was solved with a "better" cable (not even genuine cable). Maybe you could try your original cable, or borrow someone's to try (like a samsung cable). But it was just a regular cable still, nothing fancy…